# A simple Query Builder

Tags: php, oop

I try to build an Laravel like query builder, but i get an problem.

**Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\public\classes\DB.php on line 31**

```
class DB {
    private $_pdo,
    $_query,
    $_results = array(),
    $_count = 0;

    public static $instance;

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=query', 'root', '');

            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($sql){
        if($this->_pdo = $this->_pdo->query($sql)){

           while($row = $this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
               $this->_results[] = $row;

           }
        }
        return $this;
 }

 public function results(){

     return $this->_results;
 }
```

}

Comment: I guess in your query() method the property $pdo became and object of type PDO QUERY once it's assigned to it ($pdo = $pdo->query($sql)), so your need to use this property as object => `$this->_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` to `$this->_pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` or better asign the $query property to the relevant object `if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->query($sql))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
if($this->_pdo = $this->_pdo->query($sql)){
```

To:

```
if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->query($sql)){
```

**EDIT:**

Would be even better in this situation if your `$_query` was called `$_resource`.

**EDIT 2:**

For the future - you shoud check what kind of SQL you actually query in your `query` method - maybe it would be nice if for `UPDATE...` it returns / sets somewhere in your object `affected rows` and for `INSERT...` it returns / sets `last insert id`?

That would make it much more flexible - just a suggestion though :)

**EDIT 3:**

Make sure your $sql is safe / injection proof - for PDO use prepared statements:

[PDO::prepare - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$this->_query` is never being set in your query function. You are assigning `$this->_pdo` to the result of the query instead of the query variable.